# I have an ATI Radeon HD 4550; would starting to use BitCoin be worth it?

Tags: mining-profitability, mining-hardware, gpu-mining

Below average PC, wondering if it'd be worth it. The possibility of damaging my PC also exists.

Answer (score 0):

Simply put, unless you get electricity for free, **no**. Check out some of the mining calculators linked in the dup question linked in the question comment.